# How to change width for bar chart that display only 2 items?

Tags: r, charts, bar-chart

I wanted display 2 items on a bar chart. I have used the width argument to reduce the width of each bar but they still do not get adjusted. I found that by increasing the space argument the bars will get smaller, but they will be very far apart. Could anyone please help explain to me how to fix this problem? I have attached the codes and chart below for your reference. Thank you for your time.

```
predErr<-c(mars = MARS_Predictions_Err, svm = SVM_Predictions_Err)
barplot(predErr, main = "Prediction Error Bar Chart", xlab = "Models", ylab = "Err", width = 1, ylim = c(0,1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want entire plot to be narrower or only the two bars? If it is the former, you should adjust the width of the plotting device instead of the barplot.

Comment: I would like to just change only two bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play around with three parameters: `width` (sets the width of each bar), `xlim` (sets the range of the x-axis) and `space` (sets the distance between bars *as a fraction of the average bar width*).

For example, this parameter combination:

```
heights = c("m1"=2, "m2"=4)
barplot(heights, 
        xlab = "Models", 
        ylab = "Err", 
        width = c(0.1,0.1), xlim = c(0,1), space = 3)
```

gave me this result, which I believe is what you want:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to get. I believe the problem was I did not include xlim! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I generated some data. To change the distance between the bars, I used `space=1` . Is this your response to your question?

```
set.seed(100)

MARS_Predictions_Err<-rnorm(1,200)
SVM_Predictions_Err<-rnorm(1,200)

predErr<-c(mars = MARS_Predictions_Err, svm = SVM_Predictions_Err)
barplot(predErr, main = "Prediction Error Bar Chart", 
        xlab = "Models", 
        ylab = "Err", width = 3, 
        ylim = c(0,1000),
        space=1)
```

**space=1**

[image]

**space=0**
[image]